# Binding parameters with sequelize fails if multiple

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Database is Postgres (and in Sequelize there is support for bind parameter for Postgres).

Strange thing.

When running raw query and binding parameters this way:

```
return models.sequelize.query(q, {bind: ['33', 'test']}).then(function (data) {
```

Then sequelize seems to fail in binding parameters.

The query itself is something like

```
select * from A where id = $1
```

As soon as I remove the second element in the array passed to bind, the binding works.
But when there are more than one element, the $1 is not transformed to value. This is what I can see in the log.
The query when only a bind parameter is present will print

```
select * from A where id = 33
```

While the query when more than one bind parameter is added will print

```
select * from A where id = $1
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I didn't look at the real error message sent ot the client.
It had nothing to do with the number of parameters.
The problem was that using LIKE I had something like:

```
and name LIKE '%$2%'
```

This gives the error:
    bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement requires 1

Which was the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread. However, it may be a workaround for those facing this issue and using postgresql.

```
let array = ['33', 'test'];
let query = `SELECT * FROM A WHERE id::text IN(SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY($1, ','))::text)`

// Now we can run the query.
models.sequelize.query(q, {bind: [array.toString()]})
```